# choose parser based on previous results

Tags: python, haskell, pyparsing, parsec

I'm parsing several outputs and these files have two different headers:

```
header1 = " MO EIGENVALUES, MO OCCUPATION NUMBERS, AND CARTESIAN MO EIGENVECTORS AFTER SCF STEP -1"

header2 =  "MO EIGENVALUES, MO OCCUPATION NUMBERS, AND SPHERICAL MO EIGENVECTORS AFTER SCF STEP -1"
```

Based on the statement that the results are in *CARTESIAN* or *SPHERICAL* coordinates, I want to apply the corresponding parser.

In Haskell I can write a parser that decides what to do next based on previous results as follows,

```
myparser = do
    xs <- someParser
    if xs == "foo"
       then parser1
       else parser2
```

How can I create the same function in python using pyparsing?

note: I don't know *a priori* if an output is on cartesian or spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in pyparsing one would just write:

```
oneParserToRuleThemAll = header1 + parser1 | header2 + parser2
```

If the header line matches 'header1', then pyparsing will continue on and use parser1 for the rest of the parsing. Otherwise it will try to match 'header2' and if that matches, will use parser2.

One can definitely get more exotic using dynamic parser elements and parse actions. That would look like this:

```
foo_parser = ...
bar_parser = ...

variable_parser = Forward()
switch_parser = Literal("foo") | Literal("bar")
def select_variable_parser(tokens):
    if tokens[0] == "foo":
        variable_parser <<= foo_parser
    if tokens[0] == "bar":
        varaible_parser <<= bar_parser
switch_parser.setParseAction(select_variable_parser)
parser = switch_parser + variable_parser
```

Note the use of the "shift-into" operator <<= to define the variable part of the parser by inserting into the previously-defined Forward().

But this is easier to follow, I think:

```
parser = "foo" + foo_parser | "bar" + bar_parser
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an outline of a solution which should work. The idea is to implement a new parser class which runs one parser and selects between two alternatives based on the tokens returned.

```
# modeled after class And in pyparsing.py
class IfThenElse(ParseExpression):

  def __init__(self, exprs, savelist = True):
    super(IfThenElse,self).__init__(exprs, savelist)
    self.parserIf = exprs[1]     # maybe exprs[0]?
    self.parserThen = exprs[2]
    self.parserElse = exprs[3]
    self.mayReturnEmpty = all(e.mayReturnEmpty for e in exprs[2:])
    self.setWhitespaceChars( ... )
    self.skipWhitespace = self.exprs[0].skipWhitespace

  def parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions = True):
    loc, toks = self.parserIf._parse(instring, loc, doActions)

    if ...toks...:
      loc, toks2 = self.parserThen._parse(instring, loc, doActions)
    else:
      loc, toks2 = self.parserElse._parse(instring, loc, doActions)

    return loc, toks2   # maybe combine toks and toks2?

def __str__(self):
  return "blah"         # for now
```

The `if ...toks...` is where you put your switching logic.

You'll also want to implement a `__str__` method and possibly a `checkRecursion` method.

There are some details to figure out... maybe `exprs[0]` is the "if" parser instead of `exprs[1]`.

Instantiate this parser with `IfThenElse(p, q, r)` -- should have the same syntax as the `And` parser.

Comment: Interesting extension, sort of a Ternary operator class.